# $F(\sqrt d)$ is an ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

I'm trying to solve this exercise: (hartshorne Euclid and beyond ex 15.3)

Let $F$ be an ordered field, let $d>0$, and suppose that $d$ does not have a square root
in $F$. Let $F(\sqrt d)$ denote the set of all $a + b\sqrt d$, with $a, b \in F$, where $\sqrt d$ is a square root in some extension field of F.
Show how to define an ordering on $F(\sqrt d)$, with $\sqrt d > 0$, such that it becomes an
ordered field.

I tried a lot of orderings on $F(\sqrt d)$ (also $a-b\sqrt d$ iff $a^2\geq db^2$) but I always ended up in a lot of counts and cases.
does anyone have a simpler solution?
If somehow one shows that $F(\sqrt d)\subset \mathbb{R}$ then it is obviously ordered but I can't show it...

(ordering in the sense of the book)

Comment: You won't be able to show that $F(\sqrt{d})$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $ \Bbb{R}$, because it's not true in general. For example, $F$ might be the subfield of the [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) generated by a single transfinite number, and then $F$ will not be Archimedean and cannot be embedded in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought, unfortunately... So maybe I really have to check every case :(

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to show that defining $a + b\sqrt{d} > 0$ if and only if there exists a neighborhood $(e, f)$ of $d$ with $0 < e < d < f$ such that whenever $x \in F$ satisfies $x > 0$ and $e < x^2 < f$, then $a + b \cdot x > 0$, then that will satisfy the trichotomy axiom.  From there, it should be fairly easy to show the sum and product axioms work as well for this definition.  (Or similarly, use a sequence of elements of $F$ which "should" converge to $\sqrt{d}$, and define $a + b \sqrt{d} > 0$ if and only if $a + b x_n > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$.)

Answer (score 5):

If $a\ge 0,b\ge 0$ then the sign of $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is clear,

while $a-b\sqrt{d}\ge 0$ iff $a\ge b\sqrt{d}$ iff $a^2\ge b^2 d$.

It remains to check that this satisfies the ordered field axioms.

Comment: I tried this orderig but I have more than 7 cases only to show the sum axiom... there isn't a simpler way to proceed?

Comment: @reuns: you've missed the case $-a + b\sqrt{d}$. As for Izzy's comment: I don't know any way of avoiding a tedious case analysis. if you assume $F$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$, you could construct an embedding of $F(\sqrt{d})$ in $\Bbb{R}$, but that assumption is not given to you.

Comment: @RobArthan In fact iff means that it also tells us when $a-b\sqrt{d}< 0$ so $-a+b\sqrt{d}> 0$

Comment: I don't see anything tedious in the proof that it satisfies the ordered field axioms.

Comment: I have to check $(a+c)+\sqrt d (b+f)>0$ with $a+b\sqrt d>0$ and $c+\sqrt d f>0$ So the cases are 1) $a+b\sqrt d>0$ with $a>0$ $b>0$ $c>0$ $f<0$ 2) $a>0$ $b<0$ $c>0$ $f<0$ 3) $a>0$ $b>0$ $c<0$ $f>0$ and so on... and for every one I have to distinguish whether $(a+c)>0$ or not and $(b+f)>0$ or not...

Comment: I mean, it's not hard but it's really boring

Answer (score 5):

@reuns has certainly given the canonical answer (+1), but here's a solution that avoids any casework. A field admits an ordering if and only if it is [formally real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field), ie if and only if a sum of squares is never equal to $-1$; so we need only show that $F(\sqrt{d})$ has that property. Suppose otherwise for contradiction; then there are $a_i,b_i\in F$ such that $$(a_1+b_1\sqrt{d})^2+\dots+(a_n+b_n\sqrt{d})^2=-1.$$ Expanding out yields $$a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2+d(b_1^2+\dots+b_n^2)+1=-2(a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n)\sqrt{d}.$$ Since $F$ is ordered and $d$ is positive, the left hand side is a sum of non-negative elements with $1$ and hence non-zero, so $-2(a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n)$ is also non-zero. But that means we can divide out by it and obtain $\sqrt{d}\in F$, giving a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't know the definition of formally real yet... This is a good argument, even though it doesen't give me an explicit order...

Comment: hi @Izzy, no problem, happy it helped! :) formally real just means exactly what I wrote: a field is formally real if and only if $-1$ is not a sum of squares in it. unfortunately I don't think there is any way of proving that the ordering you and reuns have given satisfies the ordered field axioms without checking all the casework explicitly

Comment: The fact that formally real fields can be ordered has a complicated proof and depends on creating its real closure. I think for quadratic extensions there should be a simpler mechanism.